# Exclude base directory inside Gradle tar/zip artifacts

Tags: gradle, tar

The [maven assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) has an `includeBaseDirectory` option that (when set to false) avoids having a single top-level directory inside the tar/zip artifact with the same name as the artifact itself.

I'd like to achieve the same result with Gradle, but I don't see how. I'm using  a configuration like this:

```
task distTar(type: Tar) {
    compression Compression.GZIP
    extension "tar.gz"
}
```

I don't see any options for [the Tar task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html) that do what I want. How can I exclude the base directory in my archive with Gradle?

Comment: Have you tried to modify it via from or include method of the Tar task? Just pointing it  deeper into directory tree

Comment: @Stanislav, thanks for the pointer. I managed to figure it out using from/include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It was simpler than I thought. To copy the library dependencies into `lib` at the root of the archive, I use a [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html):

```
task distTar(type: Tar) {
    into('lib') {
        from libsDir
        include '*.jar'
    }
}
```

Similar CopySpecs can be used to copy e.g. `bin` and `conf` directories.

Answer (score 5):

By reconfiguring the [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html#distribution_plugin) (which gets implicitly applied by the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)) you can simply do (in Kotlin DSL):

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into("/")
        }
    }
}
```

This affects the output in both *Tar* and *Zip* formats.

(Disclaimer: This answer is loosely based on [this Gradle forum post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/distributions-strip-top-level-directory/14873/3)).