# Gradle - how to create distZip without parent directory?

Tags: gradle

Gradle's `distZip` task creates a zip with the following structure

```
MyApp.zip
`-- MyApp
    |-- bin
    |   |-- ...
    `-- lib
        |-- ...
```

how to skip the parent directory and just zip the files like below

```
MyApp.zip
|-- bin
|   |-- ...
`-- lib
    |-- ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude base directory inside Gradle tar/zip artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661556/exclude-base-directory-inside-gradle-tar-zip-artifacts)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible by default, but it is possible to travrse all the files, which will be included into the final zip and modify it's destination path in this zip, as:

```
distZip {
    eachFile { file ->
        String path = file.relativePath
        file.setPath(path.substring(path.indexOf("/")+1,path.length()))
    }
}
```

Here is the additional `distZip` task's configuration added, which modifies each file's destination path within the final zip-archive, deleting the root folder from it. In your case, it will delete the `MyApp` folder from the zip.

Comment: This produces strange results when other assets are included in the distribution. It correctly removes the top-level directory, but also seems to keep the original files.

Comment: @max i had a similar issue where old directories were left behind if empty.  Adding "includeEmptyDirs = false" to the "distZip" closure after the "eachFile" clause - in the answer from stanislav -  fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

In the distribution block you can define where in the archive the files should go. (example from Kotlin DSL)

```
distributions {
   main {
      contents {
          into("/")
      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: This worked for me and is much cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked as described. Straight forward and simple answer.  Bravo.

Comment: As @Ludwik mentioned, this is the correct answer. The `eachFile` solution did not work for me. Just note that if you do have `eachFile` set up somewhere, you will need to remove it for this to work.