# Gradle task to compile java files and resources to zip file

Tags: gradle, build

I'm new to Gradle and I have no past experience for Gradle builds. What I'm trying to achieve are compile Java classes, copy some files to build dir with some resource files and make a zip file of the whole directory.

Zip file contents

```
bin
----data
----java
----properties
----resources
----run.sh
----classes <---- Java compiles classes here!
lib
----sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar
properties
----MANIFEST.MF
```

I tried to Gradle build for Java but it makes too much tasks for this and I think it's overkill for my purposes. I want to write simple compile and copy task for this. Or if I need to use all java build tasks, how can I edit those task operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use both Java and Distribution plugins, that will help you to create a simple build script. Java plugin will bring you some tasks that you might not need in you case, but it still worth using it instead of creating your own task for source compilation.

An example of script you could use as a starter:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'distribution'
}

// Java plugin configuration
// ---------------------------------------------------

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.23.1'
}

// Distribution plugin configuration
// ------------------------------------------------------
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = 'myDist'
        contents {
            // 1. by default, content under /src/main/dist will be automatically included in the target dist zip

            // 2. include compiled classes output dir into  /bin/classes 
            from(project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir) {
                into('bin/classes/')
            }
            // 3. include all dependent jars into /libs
            from(configurations.compile) {
                into('libs/')
            }

            // 4. other resources to include in the target zip
            // ...

        }
    }
}

// Make distZip task depend on compileJava task
distZip {
    dependsOn compileJava
    // EDIT : change target file path 
    eachFile { file ->
        String path = file.relativePath
        String newPath = path.substring(path.indexOf("/")+1,path.length())
        println "Changed path to file from $path to $newPath"
        file.setPath(newPath)
    }
}
```

This script assumes that you follow standard directory layout in your project, for your source code and resources ( src/main/java/ , src/main/dist/  , ..), else you will have to adapt the script.

Comment: Any idea how to remove parent directory from archive?

Comment: @JarnoLahtinen with Distribution plugin i don't know if you can create the zip without the root directory; maybe you can just use the Zip task directly instead of Distribution plugin: see answer to a question similar as yours here:  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/creating-a-distribution-zip-file-without-parent-directory/11405/2

Comment: How can i now extend javaCompile to make zip package. If I make custom task to Zip, I don't have java classes available. So do I need to extend JavaCompile with doLast or something?

Comment: forget about my previous comment: there is a way customize the distribution plugin to remove the root directory from the zip archive, as described in answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427830/gradle-how-to-create-distzip-without-parent-directory .  So you can still use java and distribution plugins as suggested earlier, and just have to configure the "distZip" task .

Comment: I tried that one but no success. I still got root directory in archive.

Comment: this is strange: I could test the script I posted in my answer, with adding the 'trick' in the distZip task configuration, and I don't get the root directory in the archive anymore. I use gradle 4.9  :  could you try the script I provided, maybe this is connected to your gradle version ?

Comment: Yes, I made a clean gradle build with "gradle init type --java-application". With your modifications output is still (dist.zip -> dist -> bin/classes) etc. Gradle version is 4.9

Comment: Tried this on apache ant zip task and same thing there. Root folder is always created there and you can not automate zip file creation because you get root dir in any case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178424/discussion-between-m-ricciuti-and-jarno-lahtinen).

Comment: as discussed with Jarno in chat, the produced Zip archive was correct and did not contain the root directory anymore, using the 'trick' described in previous comments (see EDIT part in the script sample from my answer) @JarnoLahtinen feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: Correct! Extracting Zip creates folder with archive name and displays archive contents inside of it. With terminal command "zipinfo myDist.zip" reveals there are no root folder.